# Navigation within PivotItem

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm looking for a solution, if it is possible navigate within pivotitem. I have pivotitem with ListView. When I click on some item, I want to show details of the item, not to navigate on new page. So I can navigate within pivotitem on new page/control and Pivot control will be still visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show a ContentDialog? Or have a hidden "details" control so that when the item is clicked/selected, you hide the list and show the details control?
In the latter case it would be good to somehow allow the user to go back to the previous state (show the list and hide the details control), so handling the back button might not be a bad idea for this.

Comment: I was thinking about this solution. I think its a best way to realize it.